# jQuery UI: Problem customising handle on slider

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, slider

Does anyone know how to customise the slider handle in jQuery UI?

I want the handle only can be dragged within the slider background bar. But the handle is either slightly over run on the left end or on the right end.

It is over run on the left end on my localhost but it is over run on the right on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lauthiamkok/Qfc9P/).

How can I make the handle fall in exactly inside the slider background only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the width of your slider-handle into account.  Throw a margin-left:-4px on it and it appears to be fine.  (-4 because you have a width of 8)  This worked in your jsfiddle, at least.  See http://jsfiddle.net/morrison/Qfc9P/1/